# How to read image from PostAsync (HttpClient)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient

How do I read images into `ImageSource`? The source I'm suppose to get from this `Get` method is a `jpg` file, which I want to put in `ImageSource` and return it.

This is how I normally get my `Json` data:

```
   var getJson = await client.GetAsync(myUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (getJson.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var json = await getJson.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                return json
            }
```

Comment: `ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` and load to a image.

Answer (score 2):

you could try this -

```
var bytes = await getJson.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: or Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result